# Eclipse doesn't see the Log.d() method

Tags: android

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyActivity";    
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "something");
```

Eclipse is marking an error here. It doesn't know any of Log.* methods, why could be that?

EDIT: Look at the IMG

[image]

Comment: whats the error message in your android console.

Comment: in what part of your code is `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "something");`?

Comment: It's like it misses some libraries or smth... check the img out

Comment: yeah it's working project. I just wanted to print some log for debugging purposes. It's 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "something");
```

outside of the method or code block like static definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Your Log.d is outside of a method. Put it in onCreate or any other method, it should work.